# Update Breadcrumbs phtml file via local.xml

Tags: layout-update, breadcrumbs, layout

I'm trying to update the breadcrumbs phtml file being used. I've unset the existing crumb block in layout:

```
<action method="unsetChild"><name>breadcrumbs</name></action>
```

But adding the below doesn't output anything. I think the new phtml is being called (a duplicate of the default breadcrumbs.phtml), but `$crumbs` is empty:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs" template="page/html/breadcrumbs_category.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to up date the template file,so you `don't need to remove  breadcrumbs block from layout and again add breadcrumbs block.`

Just need change template file using `setTemplate` function at `layout xml`

### Code:

```
<reference name="breadcrumbs">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/breadcrumbs_category.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

May be you want for category page then use below:

```
<catalog_category_layered><!-- for Anhor Category  -->
 <reference name="breadcrumbs">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/breadcrumbs_category.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>


<catalog_category_default><!-- for Non-Anhor Category  -->
 <reference name="breadcrumbs">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/breadcrumbs_category.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

Comment: you have welcome..